# JS - How to add key:value pairs from objects nested in arrays to other objects nested in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I know it has been countlessly asked and I assure you that I've read a lot of posts, articles, etc., and watched a lot of videos but nothing seems to click.

so there we go :

Here are 2 arrays with partial information about every person

```
let arr1 = [{id:00, name:Ben, city:Philadelphia}, {id:01, name:Alice, city:Frankfurt}, {id:02, name:Detlef, city:Vienna}]

let arr2 = [{id:02, age:18}, {id:00, age:39}, {id:01, age:75}]
```

And there is the desired final result: an array including the name, city, and age of each person

```
let arr3 = [{name:Ben, city:Philadelphia, age:39}, {name:Alice, city:Frankfurt, age:75 }, {name:Detlef, city:Vienna, age:18}]
```

What's the situation? Two arrays both containing objects. each nested object has an id. That id is the common key in each array of objects.

What do you want to do? : I want to create a third array including information from both arrays (from arr1: name and city; from arr2:age).

What have you tried so far? : I couldn't manage to achieve anything worth showing. this minimal example is intended to show you a simple example of my current situation which is: I've got an array that is in the LocalStorage on one hand and an API on the other, both contain some info regarding particular objects (let's say, persons). I want to create an array that will contain all the information regarding each person for easier manipulation afterward (DOM generation, etc.).

I've managed to store both arrays in two "local" arrays but the problem is still there: I can't figure out how to make an array where items are getting their key/value from two separate sources.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is it possible that object with particular id can exist only in one of the arrays?

Comment: @MaxLysenko thank you or your comment ! No, the ids pressent in arr1 will always appear in arr2 there will never be an id that will appear only in one of the arrays. Not in my case. But thanks for asking the precision !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method on the `arr` with `array` as an inital value, and inside try to `find` the corrospending item with same `id` and destruct the object from the `id` and merge the two object with `spread operator`.

```js
let arr1 = [{id:00, name:'Ben', city: 'Philadelphia' }, {id:01, name:'Alice', city:'Frankfurt'}, {id:02, name:'Detlef', city:'Vienna'}]

let arr2 = [{id:02, age:18}, {id:00, age:39}, {id:01, age:75}]


const result = arr1.reduce((acc, { id: id1, ...rest1 }) => {
  const { id: id2, ...rest2 } = arr2.find(i => i.id === id1)
  acc.push({ ...rest1, ...rest2 })
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll check that out as soon as possible !

Comment: It works, thanks, now I have to adapt it to my own situation !

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it in various ways, here first I have implemented a `dict` with `key` as id to get the value in `O(1)` while iterating `arr2`.

So the overall time complexity is `O(n+k)` where `n` is len of `arr1` and `k` is len of `arr2`.

```js
let arr1 = [{id:00, name: "Ben", city: "Philadelphia"}, {id:01, name:"Alice", city:"Frankfurt"}, {id:02, name:"Detlef", city:"Vienna"}];

let arr2 = [{id:02, age:18}, {id:00, age:39}, {id:01, age:75}];


const refMapById = arr1.reduce((refMap, {id, name, city}) => {
  refMap[id] = {name, city};
  return refMap;
}, {});

const result = arr2.reduce((resultArray, {id, age}) => [...resultArray, { ...refMapById[id],age}], []);

console.log(result);
```

Cheers!

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'll check that one as soon as possible !

Comment: It works, thanks for it. Now I have to adapt it to my own situation as I have said to @Mina here below.

Answer (score 1):

It will be worth creating a dictionary from one of the arrays anyway since using `.find()` inside of `.reduce()` adds an unnecessary nested loop. But instead of reducing the second array as was suggested you can simply `.map()` it into the result array, like so:

```js
let arr1 = [{ id: 00, name: "Ben", city: "Philadelphia" }, { id: 01, name: "Alice", city: "Frankfurt" }, { id: 02, name: "Detlef", city: "Vienna" }];
let arr2 = [{ id: 02, age: 18 }, { id: 00, age: 39 }, { id: 01, age: 75 }];

const groupedById = arr1.reduce((group, person) => {
    group[person.id] = person;

    return group;
}, {});

const result = arr2.map((personPartFromSecondArray) => {
    const personPartFromFirstArray = groupedById[personPartFromSecondArray.id];

    if (typeof personPartFromFirstArray !== "undefined") {
        return { ...personPartFromFirstArray, ...personPartFromSecondArray }
    }

    return personPartFromSecondArray;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'll check that one as soon as possible !

Comment: I've checked your answer, copied/pasted it in VS Code and looked at the ```console.log(result)``` but couldn't get the array as you get it here (the console only show arr1 content)